# How to select manytomany objects only for the current instance

Tags: python, django

I want the many-to-many select display the values related for a current instance like this:

[In this screenshot it displays interest SQL & nage but SQL not for a current instance Hanin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2T1m.png)

[SQL interest is for person Ahmedmahmoud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6EFN.png)

[nage is for a current instance Hanin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ics8v.png)

Models.py

```
 class Formation(models.Model):
    
        Nom = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        Niveau = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        institution = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        contexte = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        Description = models.TextField()
        DateDebut = models.DateField(null=True)
        DateFin = models.DateField(null=True)
        id_candidat = models.ForeignKey(Candidat, null= True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,default=Candidat.id)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.Nom

class CV(models.Model):

    interet = models.ManyToManyField(Interet)
    candidat = models.ManyToManyField(Candidat)
    Langues = models.ManyToManyField(Langue)
    Certifications= models.ManyToManyField(Certification)
    Experiences= models.ManyToManyField(Experience)
    Competence = models.ManyToManyField(Competence)
    References= models.ManyToManyField(Réfférence)
    Declaration = models.ManyToManyField(DeclarationPerson)
    Formations = models.ManyToManyField(Formation)
```

views.py

```
def createcv(request):

 if request.method=='POST':

         cv_form=CVForm(request.POST)
         if cv_form.is_valid():

           cv_form = cv_form.save(commit=False)
           cv_form.id_candidat=
Candidat.objects.get(id=request.user.candidat.id)
           cv_form.save()
           return redirect('/resume')
    context={'cv_form':cv_form}
    return render('/')
```

### forms.py

```
class CVForm(ModelForm) :

    class Meta:
        model=CV
        fields="__all__" 
        exclude = ["candidat"]
```

Comment: check this answer https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/questions/2017/03/22/how-to-dynamically-filter-modelchoices-queryset-in-a-modelform.html  you want like this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in your `forms.py`

```
class CVForm(ModelForm) :

    class Meta:
        model=CV
        fields="__all__" 
        exclude = ["candidat"]
    interet = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=interet.objects.all(),
    )
    candidat = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=candidat.objects.all(),
    )
    Langues = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Langues.objects.all(),
    )
    Certifications = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Certifications.objects.all(),
    )
```

Comment: Does not match! you dont understand my idea i have to do an application make cv every person is an user for the application, every  cv section had relation foriegnkey refference to person model

Comment: so you want all the data related to that particular person eg. person's cv, person's language etc.

Comment: yes? exactly i get another source for that thanks https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/questions/2017/03/22/how-to-dynamically-filter-modelchoices-queryset-in-a-modelform.html

Comment: if i some how helped you please consider to accept answer